# Add an event call back to kivy RecycleView

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to create an app using kivy. I am using a RecycleView to dynamically create a bunch of buttons. My problem is that I am not sure how to bind a callback for when a button is pressed, since I am not quite sure how the code is actually making the buttons. Would I need to create a method within my RV class? And if so, how would I use it alongside the kivy language in the string builder? Additionally, how can I get access to the created buttons? Are they stored in the `self.data` variable? Lastly, are the created buttons widgets or some other type of data?

```
from kivy.app import App, ObjectProperty 
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView 
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = """
<RV>: 
    viewclass: 'Button' # defines the viewtype for the data items. 
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: 40
    padding:10, 10
    space_x: self.size[0]/3

RecycleBoxLayout: 
    color:(0, 0.7, 0.4, 0.8) 
    default_size: None, dp(56) 
    default_size_hint: 0.4, None
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height 
    orientation: 'vertical' # defines the orientation of data items
"""
Builder.load_string(KV)

class RV(RecycleView): 
    def __init__(self, **kwargs): 
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(100)]

class SampleApp(App): 
    def build(self):
        return RV() 

SampleApp().run()
```

Also, I am confused about the difference between a widget and view? Does specifying a viewclass in my  tag make a difference?

Comment: Viewclass definition: viewclass is an AliasProperty that gets and sets the class used to generate the individual items presented in the view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The callback is a property of the `Button`. You can use `on_press` or `on_release`, but they must be specified in the `data`. Here is a modified version of your `RV` class that does it:

```
class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'text': str(x), 'on_release': partial(self.butt, x)} for x in range(100)]

    def butt(self, x):
        print('button', x, 'pressed')
```

The `RecycleView` makes a bunch of instances of `viewclass` (in your case `Button`), and uses the `data` to set properties of the `Button`. So the `data` can contain any property of a `Button` as a key, with the desired value as the dictionary value. The `RecycleView` reuses (recycles) those `Button` instances and just sets the `Button` properties from the `data`. The `viewclass` can be any `Widget` class that has the properties that are in the `data`. So, an instance of a specific `Button` in your `RV` could be the one with text `10`, but later, that same button might be displayed with a different text (maybe `67`). Accessing a specific `Button` probably does not make sense. If you want to change something about a specific `Button`, you could change the `data` for that `Button`.

Comment: You can actually access specific Button or any widget using `ObjectProperty` passed for `RecycleView.data`. Look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64019775/14073186).

Comment: also note that if your recycleview's kvlang has specified labels it's generating, you can just change `Label` to `Button`, which this answer gave me the idea to do.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried inheriting Button class and make your custom Button widget ?

This works for me (using your example):

```py
from kivy.app import App, ObjectProperty 
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView 
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button

KV = """
<RV>: 
    viewclass: 'CustomButton' # defines the viewtype for the data items. 
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: 40
    padding:10, 10
    space_x: self.size[0]/3

    RecycleBoxLayout: 
        color:(0, 0.7, 0.4, 0.8) 
        default_size: None, dp(56) 
        default_size_hint: 0.4, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height 
        orientation: 'vertical' # defines the orientation of data items
"""
Builder.load_string(KV)

class CustomButton(Button):
    root_widget = ObjectProperty()

    def on_release(self, **kwargs):
        super().on_release(**kwargs)
        self.root_widget.btn_callback(self)

class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs): 
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'text': str(x), 'root_widget': self} for x in range(100)]

    def btn_callback(self, btn):
        print(btn, btn.text)

class SampleApp(App): 
    def build(self):
        return RV() 

SampleApp().run()
```

> **References:**
>
> - [Kivy Properties](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html)
> - [Python Inheritance](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inheritance-in-python/)

Answer (score 0):

on_release callback in RecycleView is the worst design I have seen in Kivy&KivyMD.

Although there is workaround like [uppon answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64019775/2775212), the principle of MVC is violated. Moreover, if it comes to dynamically add/remove items, I'm totally disappointed. I do believe there are better way to add calling instance as an argument to user-defined callback functions, using some wrapper.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).